# CJuiDatePicker select week

Tags: php, jquery, yii, datepicker

I am trying to select week using datepicker in Yii . I have the following code.

```
<?php
                $this->widget('zii.widgets.jui.CJuiDatePicker', array(
                    'name'=>'accountingweekselect',
                    'value' => date('d-M-y'),
                    'flat'=>true,               
                    'htmlOptions' => array(
                        'size' => '10',         // textField size
                    ),
                    'options'=>array(
                        'dateFormat'=>'yy-m-dd',
                        'firstDay'=> 5,
                        'onSelect' => 'js: function(dateText, inst){
                                //$("#accountingweekselect_container").datepicker("setDate",dateText );
                        }',
                        'maxDate' => 'today',
                        'selectWeek'=>true,
                    )

                ));
                ?>
```

I would liek to make it work like the following link. http://2008.kelvinluck.com/assets/jquery/datePicker/v2/demo/datePickerSelectWeek.html

Maybe i can use onselect to get the day selected and use css to highlight the row. The following code only logs the container and not the day you select.

```
'onSelect' =>
                            'js:function() {
                                // to automatically assign check out date input value
                                console.log(this);
                            }',
```

updated code

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.jui.CJuiDatePicker', array(
                    'name'=>'accountingweekselect',
                    'value' => date('d-M-y'),
                    'flat'=>true,               
                    'htmlOptions' => array(
                        'size' => '10',         // textField size
                    ),
                    'options'=>array(
                        //'dateFormat'=>'yy-m-dd',
                        'dateFormat'=>'yy-mm-dd',
                        //'firstDay'=> 5,
                        'showOtherMonths'=>true,// Show Other month in jquery
                        'selectOtherMonths'=>true,// Select Other month in jquery
                        'onSelect' => 'js: function(dateText, inst){
                            console.log($("#accountingweekselect_container div table tbody tr td").children("a.ui-state-active").html());
                            console.log($("#accountingweekselect_container div table tbody tr td.ui-datepicker-current-day").children("a").html());
                        }',
                        //'maxDate' => 'today',
                        /*'onSelect' =>
                            'js:function() {
                                // to automatically assign check out date input value
                                console.log(this);
                            }',*/
                        'selectWeek'=>true,
                    )

                ));
```

I have commented out all extra options and still doe snot work. below is code from source

```
jQuery('#accountingweekselect_container').datepicker({'dateFormat':'yy-mm-dd','selectWeek':true,'defaultDate':'03-Nov-14','altField':'#accountingweekselect'});
```

Comment: and how does this work? I don't understand the problem... You showed us what you want to achieve, but what do you have up until now? I mean how does the above code behave?

Comment: The code above displays a normal datepicker. i have googled `yii CJuiDatePicker select week` which doesn't return much.

Comment: and this line: `'selectWeek'=>true,` does nothing?

Comment: try to delete the firstDay and maxDate to see if they interfere in any way

Comment: or even the onSelect function. That should be placed in htmlOptions I think...

Comment: This has to be integrated. All the effects and functionality of the JQuery library are integrated in the Zii functionality, this I know for sure. So that line does not work because something "deactivates" it... Try to find what does that and you will be good to go ;)

Comment: commented out does not make difference. moved onselect to htmloptions - does not work

Comment: `'dateFormat'=>'yy-m-dd'` to `'dateFormat'=>'yy-mm-dd'`

Comment: and also, update the question with the current code :D

Comment: code has been updated

Comment: put the selectWeek before the onSelect... maybe it has something to do with that